# how to dynamically ng-include a new row on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, dynamic

Using Angular I would like to add rows of content dynamically to my view.

The view is currently something like:

```
       [   main-item-one   ]
 [sub-one.1][sub-one.2][sub-one.3]
       [   main-item-two   ]
 [sub-two.1][sub-two.2][sub-two.3]
```

When someone clicks on `sub-one.1` I would like to display a new row right after it:

```
             [   main-item-one   ]
click: [sub-one.1][sub-one.2][sub-one.3]
show>  [sub-o.1.1][sub-o.1.2][sub-o.1.3]
             [   main-item-two   ]
       [sub-two.1][sub-two.2][sub-two.3]
```

This process can potentially go on infinitely so I need a programmatic way of adding elements to the dom based on ng-click and perhaps ng-include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just have an array that holds all values and then on click have a function that adds to the array?

Then ng-repeat will see the new value and add it as you wish.